# How to stop Steam continually downloading and installing Mafia 2?

Tags: steam, mafia-2

I purchased a physical copy of Mafia 2 DLC edition, registered the game on Steam and used it to install the game. Once I installed the game using both DVDs, it started downloading a 7.3Gb update using Steam.

Once completed it asked to install the game again and when the installation was complete it started downloading the 7.3Gb again.

My internet connection is slow and it takes 2 days to download 7Gb.

I read on internet that other people have had a similar problem but the reported solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: HI @romhail, welcome to arqade. I have edited your question to tidy up grammar and spelling. It may be helpful other users looking to help if your added the solutions that you have already tried.

Comment: Are you sure it's **actually** downloading 7 GB? sometimes Steam just needs to update a couple of files but it lists the entire directory anyway.

Comment: I would recommend verifying the game files, to do this you have to right click on the game and view the properties, and when you select the option to verify game files, it will download all the files that are missing. I might even be less that 7gb, hope this helps

Comment: Yes. It is actually downloading all the 7 gb. I can see the downloaded files increasing 1 mb in size after every 1 minute or so. :p

Comment: I tried verify the game and it does verify it within seconds and gives a positive response but again starts downloading.

Comment: OK. So I installed the game again from the disk. Now the total game size is 7.3 gb out of which 5.3 gb is installed from the disk 1. Now instead of installing from disk 2, it starts downloading from the internet the rest of the 2 gb. I hope that after it installs the rest of the DLC content from internet, it starts to play. Will report the result. Steam should fix this issue.

Comment: what the hell. So it downloads all 7.3 gb again and then asks me to install the game. once i click install, it starts downloading again. I can see that in downloading folder, the complete game is present(size 7.8 gb disk space) but he commons folder of steam is like totally empty with all empty folders. So the game is present in downloading folder. What to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possibly because steam tries to install from their servers instead of from disk. To force steam to install from a disk, put the following into a the Run window (Windows key + R)
`"C:\Program Files\Steam\Steam.exe" -install D:`
Where 'D' is replaced with whatever drive your disk drive is. You may need to exit steam first for the command to work.

Comment: I uninstalled the steam and lost all the data. I installed the steam again and now I am installing the game again from the disk. Once it finishes the installation, if it tries to download it again from internet, i will use it and report the outcome.

Comment: what the hell. So it downloads all 7.3 gb again and then asks me to install the game. once i click install, it starts downloading again. I can see that in downloading folder, the complete game is present(size 7.8 gb disk space) but he commons folder of steam is like totally empty with all empty folders. So the game is present in downloading folder. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to run the game while steam is in Offline mode. This will allow you to see if the game does actually need to be updated. Also try going to your library and "untick" the box next to your game that allows auto updates for Mafia 2.

This is the only advice or answer I can offer, But Oil is also right I had a similar problem with the new Dota 2 update/download, and had to verify my game files and that worked for me.

I hope this helps.

Best of luck.

Comment: Offline mode is fine but when i run the game in offline mode it says that the game is not prepared yet to run on offline mode.